How do I get the contents of the downloaded file in Web mode?
I had a simple goal; the application in Web mode opens a file selection by clicking on the button. I select a config file for myself, for example, and the contents of the file appear in the TextField.
Here is my blank script, but with it I only get the name and the size of the file, not its contents:
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.padding = ft.Padding(top=60, bottom=60, left=250, right=250)

    def on_dialog_result(e: ft.FilePickerResultEvent):
        content = str(e.data) + "\n" + str(e.files)
        text_field.value = text_field.value + "\n" + content
        text_field.update()

    file_picker = ft.FilePicker(on_result=on_dialog_result)
    page.overlay.append(file_picker)
    page.update()

    text_field = ft.TextField(multiline=True, min_lines=10, max_lines=15, border_color=ft.colors.WHITE)

    page.add(
        text_field,
        ft.Row([ft.IconButton(icon=ft.icons.FILE_DOWNLOAD, bgcolor=ft.colors.INDIGO,
                              on_click=lambda _: file_picker.pick_files())],
            alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.END
        )
    )

ft.app(target=main, view=ft.WEB_BROWSER)

How can I do this?
